# Card Guessing Game Probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian, combinatorial-game-theory, card-games

Suppose we have a card game in which, for a standard deck of 52 cards, one card of each suit is selected at random and pulled out of the deck. The remaining 48 cards are shuffled together, and laid out in a random sequence, $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_{48}$. You get to look at the first 4 cards in the sequence (i.e., $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$). From there, you are supposed to guess what the last four cards are which were selected at the start of the game (meaning, you guess one card of each suit). Your guess is checked against each card in sequence until a card shows up that disproves your guess.

My question is this: Given that you do not guess any of the first four cards that you see, and that you guess one card of each suit, what is the probability that your guess is disproved at exactly card $c_k$? (Moreover, is there an answer such that the probability of being disproved at each of $c_{49}$ is 1, and at $c_{50},c_{51},c_{52}$ is each 0?)

Comment: I suggest:  divide by cases, according to how many of your guesses you got right.  As a first step, then, you'll need to compute the probabilities that you got $0,1,2,3,4$ correct.  Note:  because of the suit constraint, the make up of the exposed $4$ cards matters.  If, say, they are all spades, then the probability that you got the missing spade right is considerably higher than it otherwise would be.

Comment: It is very hard to understand the game. Please put the story in a more probabilistic setting. (So we maybe have some more precision about constructing a strategy to guess something, or about the inexistence of a strategy, if the question assumes a random guess.)

Comment: @dan_fulea the question assumes a random guess, since the only information you have is that the answer contains one card of each suit, and that none of the first four cards you look at are in the answer.